# how ui-grid can customize dynamic number of header and data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

i have a ui-grid with this structure :
http://plnkr.co/edit/qwfPVBfci4qbMEbwdNvM?p=preview
how can I customize this grid to have different number of header or data .
actualy i have to make dynamic funktion for difference kind of dataset
for example for this dataSet:

```
{0:["date","numberOfTransaction", "price"],
1:["20170207", "3029223", "5294194476028"],
2:["20170208", "2176469", "1479374036275"],
3:["20170209", "2902111", "6971208095034"],
4:["all", "8107803", "13744776607337"]}
```

or for this :

```
{0:["date","numberOfTransaction", "price","total price"],
1:["20170207", "3029223", "5294194476028","3232"],
2:["20170208", "2176469", "1479374036275","223"],
3:["20170209", "2902111", "6971208095034","322"],
4:["all", "8107803", "13744776607337","1321"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this. You should create columns of `ui-grid` firstly. then init data array of `ui-grid`. 
for this i create a function that create row of `ui-grid`. this function have a parameter that is an array. by using of this array and columns of `ui-grid` creating rows of `ui-grid`. 
after crating each row push it in data array of `ui-grid`. as you see below.

```
 var obj = {};
 var row = {};
 angular.forEach($scope.myData[0],function(data,j){
   $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({field:data});
 });
 angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(data,j){
  if(j != 0){
   row = createObject(data);
   $scope.gridOptions.data.push(row);
  }
})  

  function createObject(array){
    var obj = {};
    for(var h=0; h < array.length;h++){
      obj[$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[h].field] = array[h];
    }
  return obj;
 }
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwfPVBfci4qbMEbwdNvM?p=preview)